# Filter rows with duplicate values in certain fields based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data set that has multiple fields, list below and some are truncated for my example.

```
C_ID    O_ID    C_O_ID              PoP          PoP_End    Status  Type    Completion_ Date
WAB 0034    WAB-0034    09/25/2017 - 05/30/2018 05/30/2018  Started Interim 03/30/2019
WAB 0034    WAB-0034    09/25/2018 - 05/30/2019 03/30/2019  Started Final   03/30/2019
YSF ZA03    YSF-ZA03    06/01/2016 - 11/30/2016 11/30/2016  Completed   Final   09/30/2016
WDN PO43    WDN-PO43    09/15/2016 - 10/18/2017 10/18/2017  Pending Interim 01/18/2020
WDN PO43    WDN-PO43    09/15/2017 - 10/18/2018 10/18/2018  Pending Interim 01/18/2020
POD             POD     08/10/2015 - 04/26/2016 04/26/2016  Pending Interim 01/18/2019
POD             POD     08/10/2015 - 04/26/2016 01/18/2019  Pending Final   01/18/2019
DZE SE95    DZE-SE95    10/01/2017 - 09/30/2018 07/15/2018  Completed   Final   07/15/2018
SDF PE34    SDF-PE34    09/25/2015 - 05/30/2016 05/30/2016  Started Interim 05/30/2016
SDF PE34    SDF-PE34    06/01/2016 - 11/30/2016 05/30/2016  Completed   Final   05/30/2016
```

`C_O_ID` is a concatenation of `C_ID` and `O_ID`.
`PoP_End` is a formula that states "`If(Type = "Final", Completion_Date, Right(PoP,10))` (The last date in the date range on the PoP field).

Here are the rules:
`C_O_ID` becomes my key field that I use to look everything up and do my analysis. This field can have duplicates which I am trying to remove with the logic below.

In order to get the unique `C_O_ID`, I use the `MAX(PoP_End)`.

Query1

```
SELECT C_O_ID, MAX(PoP_End) AS Max_PoP_End
FROM table
GROUP BY C_O_ID
```

Then, I use a `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the other data

```
SELECT q.C_O_ID, q.Max_PoP_End, t.PoP, t.Status, t.Type, t.CompletionDate
FROM Query1 q LEFT JOIN table t
ON query1.C_O_ID = table.C_O_ID AND query1.Max_PoP_End = table.PoP_End
```

However, I run into issues because what happens is sometimes because of the `If` statement I have to calculate the `PoP_End` in `table`, there are duplicate combination of `C_O_ID` and `PoP_End`.

My first SQL query is great. I get the following.

```
C_O_ID       PoP_End
WAB-0034    03/30/2019
YSF-ZA03    11/30/2016
WDN-PO43    10/18/2018
POD         01/18/2019
DZE-SE95    07/15/2018
SDF-PE34    05/30/2016
```

However, once I left join, since there are duplicate matches now for `SDF-PE34`, it will duplicate it on the join the way I do it.

Since I want a unique list of `C_O_ID` based on the latest `PoP_End` and I want to bring in all the other fields, I was not quite sure how to do that with aggregate functions or joining tables and keep a unique list of `C_O_ID` with all the row data for that latest `PoP_End`. Also, if `Type` = "Final" and `Status` = Completed and the `RIGHT(PoP,10)` is LESS THAN `Completion_Date`.

I would like my results to be the following.

```
C_ID    O_ID    C_O_ID  PoP Max_PoP_End Status  Type    Completion_Date
WAB 0034    WAB-0034    09/25/2018 - 05/30/2019 03/30/2019  Started Final   03/30/2019
WDN PO43    WDN-PO43    09/15/2017 - 10/18/2018 10/18/2018  Pending Interim 01/18/2020
POD     POD 08/10/2015 - 04/26/2016 01/18/2019  Pending Final   01/18/2019
DZE SE95    DZESE95 10/01/2017 - 09/30/2018 07/15/2018  Completed   Final   07/15/2018
SDF PE34    SDF-PE34    06/01/2016 - 11/30/2016 05/30/2016  Completed   Final   05/30/2016
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or my logic is not clear.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 t.C_O_ID, t.Max_PoP_End, t.PoP, t.Status, t.Type, t.CompletionDate
FROM table as t
WHERE t.C_O_ID IN (SELECT C_O_ID FROM Query1)
ORDER BY Pop_End`

Comment: Once I get access to my system again, I will try that. Wow, that does make a lot of sense though! If `Type` was "Interim" vs "Final", I could second `ORDER BY` `Type'. I can't wait to test it! I hope there isn't a case where there are 2 rows with the same `PoP_End` date and different data in the other fields. However, I think the second `ORDER BY PoP_End, Type` would solve it since I do not believe it is possible for 2 "Interim"s to have the same `PoP_End`.

Comment: Let me know if it works out

Comment: It seems to be only pulling 1 record and the query does take some time to run. I am using MS Access 2013, which I should have indicated earlier. I used the same query you stated and I brought in all the other fields as well. Do I need to do a GROUP BY or anything so it pulls the TOP 1 from each SUBSET of C_O_IDs? I am not sure how to perform that.

Comment: Hey @BankBuilder, just seeing if I could get your help since I have not been able to get it to work yet. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I have also tried several other methods with `Union` and the one suggested by Perry below, but I have not had success.

Comment: Try `SELECT t.C_O_ID, Max(t.PoP_End), t.PoP, t.Status, t.Type, t.CompletionDate FROM table as t WHERE t.C_O_ID IN (SELECT C_O_ID FROM Query1) GROUP BY t.C_O_ID, t.PoP, t.Status, t.Type, t.CompletionDate`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work @BankBuilder. I believe it is because the subquery has the "unique" list of `C_O_ID`s, but there are multiple instances in `table` so it is pulling all the values. Whereas, I am only looking for the record with the latest `PoP_End` based on the logic in the original post and all the associated data. I appreciate your reply! Please tell me if you think I did something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

How about including the status in query 1 and maximize the status, either by codifying it or actually comparing it. 
Then when you left join you can include the status and get the latest status on the latest date.

Comment: If I understood your suggestion correctly, I believe that would get me duplicate values still. ` SDF-PE34` has multiple entries and varying `Status` for each entry. I can't distinguish between the newest entry and an older entry based on `Status`, only by a combination of the `Type` if it's "Final", then that automatically is the newest. If there are multiple "Interim" entries, then I would have to look at the date on the right of the `PoP`range. Please tell me if I interpreted it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My Query1 (I named your table Monkey)
**SELECT Monkey.C_O_ID, Max(Monkey.[Pop_end]) AS Max_Pop_End, Last(Monkey.Status) AS               LastOfStatus FROM Monkey GROUP BY Monkey.C_O_ID;**
My Query2
**SELECT Query1.C_O_ID, Monkey.Pop, Monkey.Pop_end, Monkey.Status, Monkey.Type, Monkey.Complettion_Date FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN Monkey ON (Query1.Max_Pop_End = Monkey.Pop_end) AND (Query1.C_O_ID = Monkey.C_O_ID);**
My Query3 (Needed because Access SQL has trouble with Multiple Outer Joins)
**SELECT Query2.C_O_ID, Query2.Pop, Query2.Pop_end, Query2.Status, Query2.Type, Query2.Complettion_Date FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN Query2 ON (Query1.Max_Pop_End = Query2.Pop_end) AND (Query1.C_O_ID = Query2.C_O_ID) AND (Query1.LastOfStatus = Query2.Status);**
My results were the results you are looking for. I used Last of Status because I believe your data is sorted. It will need to be. You might choose to use type. But I think this is the idea and you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: Sorry about the Bold face instead of code but I was having trouble getting the blanks in the right place for the code snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to test it until Monday. What is the purpose of having the `Last(Monkey.Status` if the `Max(Monkey.[PoP_End]` already aggregates and gives me a unique list of `C_O_ID`? Wouldn't Query2 introduce duplicates from the left join because of "SDF-PE34" has a `PoP_End`="05/30/2016" for 2 records. Unless that is the reason for the `Last` and Query3, which I will have to see in action then. I appreciate you taking the time to reply!

Comment: On your Query3, you use all the fields from Query2 and then have Query1 listed in your `FROM` clause and the `LEFT JOIN`. I am assuming you are pulling `Query1.C_O_D` and the rest from `Query2`. From the initial look, it appears to be functioning exactly like I need! I am going to dive into the data to make sure it pulled the correct elements now. I really appreciate your assistance in this! I will report back as soon as I am done validating.

Comment: Okay, I have validated the data and it seems like some rows are incorrect. When I look at the results of Query3, there are rows that have `C_O_ID`s, but the other fields in the row are blank. I also notice that at least in the 7 rows that I was able to identify, the result of Query1 has incorrect data. It pulls in the wrong `Max_PoP_End` value. I look in the table `Monkey` and I filter by the `C_O_ID` so I see all the data that is associated with it. There are multiple entries associated and only one `Type` = "Final". I changed the `LAST(Monkey.Status)` to `LAST(Monkey.Type)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Query1

`SELECT 
 Table1.C_O_ID, 
 Max(Table1.PoP_End) AS Max_PoP_End, 
 Last(Table1.Type) AS LastOfType
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.C_O_ID;`


Query2
`SELECT 
 Query1.C_O_ID, 
 Table1.PoP, 
 Table1.PoP_End, 
 Table1.Status, 
 Table1.Type,
 Table1.Completion_Date
FROM Query1
LEFT JOIN Table1
ON Query1.Max_PoP_End = Table1.PoP_End AND Query1.C_O_ID=Table1.C_O_ID;`

Comment: Query3
`SELECT 
 Query1.C_O_ID, 
 Query2.PoP, 
 Query2.PoP_End, 
 Query2.Status, 
 Query2.Type, 
 Query2.Completion_Date 
FROM Query1
LEFT JOIN Query2
ON Query1.Max_PoP_End=Query2.PoP_End AND Query1.C_O_ID=Query2.C_O_ID AND [Query1.LastOfType=Query2.Type;`